# Write a trigger that accepts a user_id

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, supabase

When creating a new user in Postgres, I have a trigger that automatically creates a chat for him (like saved messages in telegram). I also have a chat_members table in the database that stores chat members in a many-to-many relationship of users and chats. I need to write a trigger that triggers when creating any chat and will automatically insert its creator to the `chat_members` table, but I don’t know how to pass the user_id, since there is no such column in the chats table. My db schema on Supabase:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9zpG.png]

One solution is to add a `created_by` column in the chat table, and write the chat creator there, and then the trigger takes that id and creates an entry in the `chat_members` table.

Answer (score 0):

You would just create your trigger and use the `auth.uid()` as the `user_id` since the user creating the chat would be signed in I assume. You can access the `auth.uid()` inside any trigger function.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to keep the record of person who created the chat.
Its good idea to add `created_by` field in table. But still you will need to add that person in `chat_members` table. I am expecting that column `role` will serve for the same purpose.

You can write a custom function/trigger which inserts in other(chat_members) table.

Something like this: (pseudocode as i could not test)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_chat_member(
    argument1 integer,
    .....,
    .....,
    argumentN datetime
)
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL  
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO chat_members (chat_id, user_id, role, last_action, created_at)
    VALUES (arguments here);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```